# How to replace the content of my xml file in php?

Tags: php, arrays, xml, multidimensional-array, arraylist

I know to translate the content of my XML file. For that I extract the code with the function file_get_contents and I convert it into text with the library Html2Text. I have translated the content of the file, but when I get to the end to replace the content with two arrays using the str_replace function, it does not work too well. There is a part that is translated and another that is not.

**Here is my code**

```
// We will return our text in an array.
        $explodesTextForTranslatingArr = array_filter( explode(WEBSITE_NAME, $textForTranslating), 'strlen' );
        $explodesTextForTranslatingArr = array_map('trim', $explodesTextForTranslatingArr);
        $countExplodestextForTranslating = count($explodesTextForTranslatingArr);

        // We will return our text that we have translated into an array.
        $explodesTextAddForTranslatingArr = array_filter( explode(WEBSITE_NAME, $textTranslating), 'strlen' );
        $explodesTextAddForTranslatingArr = array_map('trim', $explodesTextAddForTranslatingArr);
        $countExplodesTextAddForTranslating = count($explodesTextAddForTranslatingArr);

$textForTranslatingArr = [];

            foreach ($explodesTextForTranslatingArr as $value) {

                if (!empty($value)) {
                    $textForTranslatingArr[] = $value;
                }
            }

            $textAddForTranslatingArr = [];

            foreach ($explodesTextAddForTranslatingArr as $value) {
                if (!empty($value)) {
                    $textAddForTranslatingArr[] = $value;
                }
            }

            $updateAllContentFromXml = str_replace($textForTranslatingArr, $textAddForTranslatingArr, $fileGetContentFileXml);
            
            echo '<pre>';
            print_r($fileGetContentFileXml);
```

**Here is a snippet of the result of my XML file:**

```
<book id="bk101">
      <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
      <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>44.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
      <description>An in-depth look at building applications 
      with XML.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk102">
      <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
      <title>Midnight Rain</title>
      <genre>Fantasy</genre>
      <price>5.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-12-16</publish_date>
      <description>A former architect battles corporate zombies, 
      an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen 
      of the world.</description>
   </book>
```

**EDIT:**
**Here are some essential explanations on the use of its three variables.**

The variable **$textForTranslatingArr** store the text for translation in the array by filtering the data to remove the site name in the text.

The variable **$textAddForTranslatingArr** will add the translated text into a new array. By filtering the data i.e. by removing the name of the site and the spaces that we had in the previous text.

The variable **$fileGetContentFileXml** will display the content of our XML file and this content will be replaced by our translated content. This content is stored in the variable $textAddForTranslatingArr. Now I explain you the functionality of these three variables, what should I do so that I can solve this bug please?

**I don't know why all the content is not translated exactly as it is in the array. Can you give me an idea or show me where I made the mistake in my code please?**

Comment: I might be able to help if you clarified exactly what data was in: `$textForTranslatingArr`, `$textAddForTranslatingArr`, and `$fileGetContentFileXml`. I don't like the number of cycles being used to filter the input.  It seems to me that a clever regex pattern with `preg_split()` and `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY` would do the job in one go.  Please clarify your [mcve].

Comment: @mickmackusa I just changed the content of my question to explain my bug a bit more. Now, how can you please help me?

Comment: I understand the intention of your code.  What I cannot do is reproduce the failure because I don't have access to all of the ingredients / input data.  The longer you withhold these critical details, the longer you will probably have to wait for support.

Comment: Well, then you can either delete your question or update it and potentially receive some good advice.